# Seeking birth and/or death certificate for Ian Symington Torrance who died in South Africa in 1970?

Tags: birth-records, death-records, south-africa, 1970s

Seeking a copy of the birth and/or death certificates of Ian Symington Torrance who died near Johannesburg (South Africa) in 1970.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Do you know roughly when (and where) Ian was born?  I think it would be preferable for you to ask about his birth and death in separate questions.

Comment: I've chosen this duplicate on the assumption that Ian was born in South Africa before 1900.  If that is not the case please [edit] your question to provide more details so that it may be re-opened.